# Which one is more natural and correct: "be the best among a group of people" or "all of a group of people be the best"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell which one of the following sentences sounds the most correct and natural?

> Nadia is the best at math **among** her friends.
>
> **Of all of** Nadia's friends she is the best at math.

If neither sentence sounds particularly good, then what would you say to communicate the message?

Comment: They are just two different ways of saying the same thing; neither is more correct than the other (though I would leave out the second _of_).

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence makes sense because both suggest that Nadia is one of her own friends.

"*Of all of Nadia's friends...*" or "*among Nadia's friends*" indicates a group of people that don't include Nadia because she is not one of her own friends. So both sentences are nonsense. They are equivalent to saying:

> Among the women I know, Mark is the tallest. (Mark is a man)

Nadia is a member of her *group* of friends, so correct and natural ways of expressing the idea about Nadia's math skills would be:

- *Nadia is the best at math among her **group of** friends*
- ***Within** Nadia's **group of** friends, she's the best at math*

Answer (score 0):

I feel like "Nadia is the best at math among her friends" is the better sentence here. It is more specific and sounds natural. The second sentence is not at the same level as the first. There is an unspecific pronoun "she" which can be misinterpreted.

Comment: Then you could say "Of all her friends, Nadia is the best at math"